# Error in heroku using jade

Tags: node.js, heroku, pug

I have an error when the `render` function is called [this app runs on Heroku]

web.js:

```
var async   = require('async');
var express = require('express');
var util    = require('util');

// create an express webserver
var app = express.createServer(
  express.logger(),
  express.static(__dirname + '/public'),
  express.bodyParser(),
  express.cookieParser(),
  // set this to a secret value to encrypt session cookies
  express.session({ secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET || 'secret123' }),
);

app.set('views', __dirname + 'views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// listen to the PORT given to us in the environment
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Listening on " + port);
});



app.get('/', function ( req, res ) {
    res.render('ok', { title : 'ok' });
});
```

ok.jade:

```
!!! 5
  html(lang='en')  
    head
      title= title   
    body 
      div#navigation
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name":    "package",
  "version": "0.0.1",

  "description": "Facebook integration, Node.js",

  "dependencies": {
    "express": "latest",
    "jade":"0.17.0"
  },

  "engines": {
    "node": "0.8.19",
    "npm" : "1.2.10"
  }
}
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at new View (/app/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:41:65)
    at Function.app.render (/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:486:12)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:753:7)
    at /app/web.js:32:9
    at callbacks (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:161:37)
    at param (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:135:11)
    at pass (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:142:5)
    at Router._dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:170:5)
    at Object.router (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
    at next (/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:199:15)
```

If I replace `res.render('ok', {title : 'ok'});` by `res.end('some text');` works perfectly.

Any solution?

Thanks!

Comment: If you go through [the express source code][1]

You'll see that `express/lib/view.js:41:65` refers to `this.defaultEngine[0]` this means options.defaultEngine passed to the View constructor is undefined.

This in turn gets called from this bit of code:

    `if (!view) {
      view = new View(name, {
      defaultEngine: this.get('view engine'),
      root: this.get('views'),
      engines: engines
    });`

This means `this.get('view engine')` is not working correctly. Are you sure jade is set up properly?



  [1]: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/view.js

Comment: The problem is Jade, I'm sure, but I don't know how to solve this problem!

Comment: How are you _so_ assured the problem is with Jade?

Answer (score 2):

Latest version of Express seems to use app.engine() instead of app.set('view engine') ([doc](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.engine))

```
app.engine('jade', require('jade').__express);
```

You can have more details looking at [this function source](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L138).

This may solve your problem.

Also, add '/' to the path of your views (or remove it as [it's default](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L82) in express)

Edit: I checked if "view engine" setting was used somewhere and [it is](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L485) and, like Benjamin said, I don't see why your call to `app.set('view engine')` didn't work.

Edit 2: I just tried to run your code and there was several points of failure. Here is a fixed web.js file that works on my local computer:

```
var express = require('express');
var util    = require('util');

// create an express webserver
var app = express(
  express.logger(),
  express.static(__dirname + '/public'),
  express.bodyParser(),
  express.cookieParser(),
  // set this to a secret value to encrypt session cookies
  express.session({ secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET || 'secret123' })
);

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// listen to the PORT given to us in the environment
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Listening on " + port);
});



app.get('/', function ( req, res ) {
    res.render('ok', { title : 'ok' });
});
```

Changelog:

- removed `require('async')` as it's unused and not in the package.json
- use of express() instead of the deprecated '.createServer'
- added the missing `/` in view directory path setup
- removed the comma after the `express.session` call

Todo on your side:
 - remove the indent before `html` in your`ok.jade` file.